# Retrieve id after .commit()

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to pick up SQLalchemy and run constantly run into the following problem:
is there a way to retrieve some sort of a metadata string from `session.commit()`, which contains the current primary `id` SQLalchemy just created ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply get it from the SQLA object following its commit:

```
my_record= MyTable(id=None, FieldA='testing')
cs.add(myTable)
cs.commit()
print(my_record.id)  # will be the primary id assuming it is autoincrement
```